# render within a render? render @category with render @product

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I currently have a menu/store front page that renders categories and underneath the products that are assigned to that category.

But, I need to change it too a render @ category and a render @ product but I'm unsure how to interlink these and render the products that are assigned to the category for each category....

If anyone could tell me how this would work I will be very grateful...

**View**

```
 <body class="font-sans container">
      <div class="w-full md:w-3/5 mx-auto p-8">
         <p> <strong>Drink</strong></p>
         <div class="shadow-md">
          <% cache @categories do %>
            <% @categories.where(user_id: @account.id).each do |category| %>
              <% cache category do %>
            <div class="tab w-full overflow-hidden border-t">
               <input class="absolute opacity-0 " id="tab-multi-<%= category.category%>" type="checkbox" name="tabs">
               <label class="block p-5 leading-normal cursor-pointer" for="tab-multi-<%= category.category%>"> <%= category.category%> </label>
                <% cache @products do %>
                <% @products.where(user_id: @account.id, category: category, available: 't').each do |product| %>
                <% cache product do %>
               <div class="tab-content overflow-hidden border-l-2 bg-gray-100 border-indigo-500 leading-normal">
                 <ul class="flex flex-col p-2 ">
                    <li class="border-gray-400 flex flex-row mb-2">
                      <div class="lg:w-1/4 lg:mr-8 w-full select-none cursor-pointer bg-gray-100 rounded-lg flex flex-1 items-center p-4  transition duration-500 shadow ease-in-out transform hover:-translate-y-1 hover:shadow-lg">
                        <div class="flex-1 pl-1 mr-16">
                          <div class="font-semibold"><%= product.title %></div>
                          
                          <div class="text-gray-600 font-medium text-sm maxlength="10>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div>
                        </div>
                            <div class="flex-2 pl-1 mr-0">
                          <div class="font-semibold"><%= product.price %></div>
                          <%= button_to '+', line_items_path(product_id: product), class:"text-black font-medium text-sm mt-8 px-4 py-2 bg-blue rounded-full" %>
                        <div id="<%= product.id %>"></div>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                <% end %>
                <% end %>
                <% end %>


            </div>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
```

**Controller**

```
>   def menu
>     @products = Product.order(:title)
>     @categories = Category.order(:category)
>     @account = User.find_by_id(params[:id])
>     render layout: false   end
```

Comment: Read up about [partials](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)

Comment: This code has a huge n+1 query problem. For every iteration you're calling `@products.where(user_id: @account.id, category: category, available: 't')` will fire an additional database query. Use assocations and eager loading and don't put SQL queries in your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partials to achieve what you're looking for. When you render a partial, you can pass in local variables, like this:

```
<%= render 'partial_location', local_variable: variable_name %>
```

The, in the partial view, you can access the local variable with the `variable_name` like this:

```
<% variable_name.each do |variable| %>
  'Do something with the variable'
<% end %>
```